# Morphisms of varieties equal over algebraic closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two schemes of finite type over a field $k$. Fix an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$.

Under which conditions on $X$, $Y$ and $k$ is it true that for any two given $k$-morphisms $f$ and $g$ from $X$ to $Y$, if 
$$
f\otimes 1 = g\otimes 1 : X \otimes_k \overline{k} \to Y \otimes_k \overline{k}
$$
then $f=g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always true. No hypotheses on $X$ and $Y$ are needed.

First, note that $X \otimes_k \bar{k} \to X$ is an epimorphism; in fact, it is a faithfully flat quasicompact morphism (because $\bar{k}$ is a faithfully flat $k$-algebra), so the fundamental descent theorem says it is an effective epimorphism. Then, for each of $f : X \to Y$ and $g : X \to Y$, we have a commutative square of the form below,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \otimes_k \bar{k} @>>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
Y \otimes_k \bar{k} @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
so if $f \otimes_k \bar{k} = g \otimes_k \bar{k}$, then the two composites $X \otimes_k \bar{k} \to X \to Y$ are equal, thus $f = g$.